# Pauli-Lubasnki pseudovector on tensor field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, poincare-symmetry

We had the infinitesimal Poincaré transformations in the lecture with the Pauli-Lubanski vector:

$$W^{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}P_{\nu}M_{\rho\sigma}$$
with:

$$P_{\nu}=-\partial_{\nu} \quad \text{and} \quad M_{\rho\sigma}=x_\rho\partial_\sigma-x_\sigma\partial_\rho+\Sigma_{\rho\sigma}$$

so that the Pauli-Lubanski vector becomes:

$$W^{\mu}=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu \Sigma_{\rho\sigma} $$

I try to let it act on a antisymmetric tensor field $f^{\alpha\beta}=-f^{\beta\alpha}$ so that:
$$W^{\mu} f^{\alpha\beta}=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu\Sigma_{\rho\sigma} (f^{\alpha\beta})\\=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu \left[(\Sigma_{\rho\sigma})^{\alpha}_{\space\space\tau}f^{\tau\beta}+(\Sigma_{\rho\sigma})^{\beta}_{\space\space\tau} f^{\alpha\tau} \right]\\
=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu \left[\delta^{\alpha}_{\rho}\eta_{\sigma\tau}f^{\tau\beta}+\delta^{\beta}_{\rho}\eta_{\sigma\tau}f^{\alpha\tau}\right]\\
=-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\sigma}\partial_\nu \eta_{\sigma\tau}f^{\tau\beta} -\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\beta\sigma}\partial_\nu \eta_{\sigma\tau}f^{\alpha\tau}   $$

and at this point I am stuck. I can act $\eta$ on the Levi Civita and bring down one index but cant see how that brings me any further.  Are there some major mistakes I made? Would appreciate some hints! Thanks!

Comment: what is $\eta$? shouldnt $\partial\eta=0$? and what result are you expecting to get? any reason to believe your expression can be simplified further?

Comment: $\eta$ ist the metric tensor. I should get an expression $\approx \varepsilon \cdot \partial \cdot f$ but not sure with which indices and factors